# Unity3D and OpenCV integration and passing each other camera frames

Tags: performance, opencv, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

**Background:**

I've been working on an AR project using Unity3D and OpenCV. The integration has been done in the following way.

Our OpenCV program and the OpenCV library itself compiles into a single dynamic library (`so` file Linux). (OpenCV library is linked to statically)

Then, in Unity3D, in a C# script we import it (`DllImport`) and use its functionalities.

So far everything looks clear, but the problem is here: Both parts (Unity3D and OpenCV) need every frames of the camera, so there are multiple ways to give them camera frames:

1. Unity3D reads frames (`WebCamTexture`) and sends them via converting to three 2D arrays and passing to OpenCV part. (In this way, OpenCV part does not have access to camera)
2. OpenCV part reads frames (`VideoCapture::open`) and sends back to Unity3D. (In this way, Unity3D does not have access to camera)
3. Both parts are allowed to open the camera.

Note that the major processing is done in the OpenCV part and Unity3D only needs frames to show a camera preview.

**Question:**

It's all about performance! Which approach is the best way in performance and being the best-practice point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance, you should either go with *#2* or make your own plugin that access the camera directly.

Your *#1* option with `WebCamTexture` is the easiest method but the big problem with it is that it doesn't provide enough frame to perform video processing.

Also, `WebCamTexture` has a limitation for image size it can return on both iOS and Android which means that the quality of image you get will not be the-same as that the one the device can provide. So provides low quality image from the camera. Most video processing API such as Vuforia uses their own native API to receive frame and that you should also do.

`WebCamTexture` is not suitable for this.

Comment: Thanks for your input.